# Any advice for Git workflow using branch per development team (and not per feature)

Tags: git, version-control, branching, scm

In our project, we have 5 teams working on a monolithic application in 3-week sprints. Until now, all commits go into master (via Gerrit). Our test pipeline is too lengthy to ensure quality pre-commit, so we have to accept that some commits break things. I'm aware that the root cause here is the pipeline, and a breaking commit should never reach master. We have to accept this, however, until our pipeline redesign is complete, and this will take several months in the least.

We're now discussing the approach of "team branches", where each team would develop and commit on their own branch, and update the master periodically. The heated part of the discussion revolves around merge or rebase. Our current understanding is:

**Rebase**

1. On branch-team1: `git rebase origin/master`
2. Resolve conflicts
3. Push to branch: `git push origin branch-team1 --force-with-lease`
4. Finally, rebase master: `git rebase branch-team1`

With this approach we see commit IDs changing (due to rebase + push --force), and part of our change history is invisible to Gerrit. The former has the effect that the entire team needs to halt work during the rebase, as their un-pushed work might get messed up due to the changing commit history.

On the plus side, this approach yields an easily readable history on master. Each commit is visible, and can be cherry picked or reverted.

**Merge**

1. On master: `git merge origin/branch-team1` (+ resolve conflicts)
2. On branch-team1: `git rebase origin/master`

The main concern expressed here is that the history becomes much harder to read, as the master will mainly contain large "composite merge commits". For debugging/blaming, the associated team branch would have to be checked for the further history. Also, reverting a single commit (originally on a team branch) becomes more tedious.

However, a short proof-of-concept indicates that the history is no different to the Rebase approach, except for the actual merge commit. Similarly, cherry picks / reverts seem just as easily done, with the sole exception being if part of the cherry pick / revert would actually be a change made during conflict resolution and thus part of the merge commit. This, however, seems a tad far-fetched.

**A third way?**

It seems both approaches have negative aspects (personally I don't see much negative in the merge approach, but others on our project are clearly against it). It's a bit hard to believe that with the power and popularity of GIT, there isn't an established approach available which doesn't require squabbling over.

Does anyone have some practical experience to share here?

Comment: my advice : dont

Comment: have you considered and rejected standard approaches such as featurebranches/gitflow etc

Comment: Why are you rebasing and force-pushing public history? I can’t wrap my head around that. If you want to rebase local commits, fine; I do it all the time. Once it’s pushed, try to leave it (excepting security issues, etc.).

Comment: @Ewan, thanks for your input. We're considering basically everything, but our lengthy test pipeline is limiting our options. Feature braches would, afaik, mean more branches, thus more pipelines, and we can't go there.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, I'm with you, but we have people on our team who quite strongly feel this is the best way forward. I'm looking for someone who has practical experience with team branches and can shed some light on the do's and dont's.

Comment: @Simon you dont test on feature branches

Comment: It seems like your testing pipeline is a problem. You should be able to test a team's branch before merging into master, preferably after merging master into it. Is it just a matter of computing resources, or does the testing need to be babysat?

Comment: Never, ever, ever force-push public history. On my very first project using git, I fixed minor bug, tested it and merged it with master. Two months later, the bug re-appeared. Someone had force-pushed history and overwritten my bug-fix. So, no. Don't. Do. That.

Comment: I'm continually surprised by the number of people suggesting elaborate rebase strategies with long lists of well-known problems, followed by "but the history will look nice". Why is this such a popular sentiment? There's probably a political allegory in there somewhere.

Comment: @useless im always tempted to write a git client that displays the commits as if they had been rebased. ie in order on one line skipping merge commits. But im pretty sure you can tick some boxes in source tree and it will do exactly that

Answer (score 2):

If you had to say one way which was 'standard' branching model for git it would be gitflow.

Many people find its not for them, but don't try to invent a new model until you've tried it.

Rebasing is bad, it deletes your commits and screws over anyone else using the branch. Never rebase. Especially never rebase if the only thing you don't like about merging is the way your source control browser presents the history of commits. Most tools offer various ways to display the history, exclude merge commits, only merge commits etc etc and the way the tool displays the history has no effect on the finished product.

Cherry picking is bad, it tricks you into thinking you can take random changes to your code base and expect them to compile out of sequence with the other changes. Never cherry pick.

The key thing with any branching model is to try and minimise difficult merges. One of the key causes of these is long lived branches. The longer a branch is being worked on without being merged the higher the chance that you will get a conflict when you come to merge it.

Your team branching model would result in lots of long lived branches, each written by people who are not working together and don't understand each others changes.

Your sprint is too long. Reduce it to 1 week sprints. This will increase the frequency and decrease the size of merges.

Your monolith is too monolith. Split it into smaller components and move each component onto its own git repo/build chain. This will decrease the number of people working on the same repo and thus merges

Comment: This answer feels... dogmatic. *Rebasing is bad*; *never rebase*—false. Rebasing is great for cleaning up a bunch of local wip commits into a nice, clean history, adding substantial detail to commits if its been omitted, getting rid of the unnecessary, etc. It’s like refactoring. It gets a bad rap bc it can be difficult, and bc newcomers try to rebase public history (usually not what you want). *Cherry-picking is bad*—open source disagrees. If your PR contains too much unrelated content, but an individual change has value and is a coherent commit, it might be cherry-picked. …

Comment: … Agree with you on difficult merges and long-running branches—this can be minimised, however, by periodic merges from master into the feature. *Your sprint is too long*; *your monolith is too big*—critically examining the dev model might yield some reward in productivity, but this is dogma (even if I agree it will likely help). Overall, I agree with the spirit of the answer (__especially__ the “don’t be concerned about how merge commits look part”), but it seems too couched in absolutes. If you know your tools, you know that each blade and edge has its purpose.

Comment: my other dogmatic advice includes "always wear a life jacket", "never turn traction control off", "wear a cycle helmet" etc If your biggest problem is "my comments are too verbose" you are ready to try rebasing out

Answer (score 0):

First, if Gerrit loses some changes on "external" branch rebasing, it looks fairly natural due to its approach to keep a branch per change: with rebasing of basic branch, these changes start hanging on thin air. Gerrit is nearly the best Git server, but it was not designed for such actions: once a commit is submitted to a branch, it shall never change. You may, of course, develop a tool which updates all proposed commit branches like `refs/changes/56/123456/3`... if this is feasible (well, work amount is huge, but what if some rebase fails?)

So, the only approach which looks proper with Gerrit is to use only merges and not rebases of submitted commits. Otherwise, you should use another server (Gitlab, BitBucket, etc.), losing all Gerrit merits but allowing freedom of rebases.

A possible (and used) manner with Gerrit is to allow proposing merge commits from users. Our neighbor department actively uses it. With this manner, merge commits are sendable but merge by Gerrit itself is prohibited. You should merge parent (master, develop...) branch to inferior (per-team) one often enough to minimize merge conflicts, solve conflicts locally, and propose a working version. After this, similarly, merge team branch to common parent. If needed, an automated external checker should be configured to check requirements (setting Verified flag). This will look similar to "gitflow" but with Gerrit advantages.